# Difference between predict() and fitted.values() in lm()

Tags: lm, predict

I've found some little differences between predict() and fitted.values() functions in the next code:

> Data<-data.frame(Response=rep(c(1,2,3,4),c(96,104,110,107)),Explicative=rep(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),c(61,28,7,68,23,13,58,40,12,53,38,16)))

> Fit<-lm(Response~Explicative,data=Data)

> table(fitted.values(Fit))

2.44139273356383 2.44139273356399 2.44139273356402 2.63667820069204 2.63667820069205
1                1              238               66               63
2.83196366782007
48

> table(predict(Fit))

2.44139273356403 2.63667820069205 2.83196366782008
240              129               48

Does anybody found something similar?, What's the problem?

After reading help pages I haven't found a response